# EF: Getting "The model backing ...has changed" error, though I've altered well the schema

Tags: entity-framework, alter

I am not worried about rollbacks (ie: Down() method), and would like to work always on the latest code modification, so I'm not using Code Migrations.

I changed this:

```
 int SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

To this:

```
 int? SomeProperty {get; set;}
```

And then I modified the database schema (altering the column SomeProperty to allow NULLS).

Although this last part, I'm still getting the error:

```
The model backing the <Database> context has changed ...
```

**What other change do I need to do so that the schema matches the model if that (int to int?) is the only change I've done?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real answer to this is a bug in EF. 
In Global.asax.cs this line is needed:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        //...

        // Weird fix before using any DbContext instance <--- THIS
        Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tell EF you want to do an automatic migration

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDbContext, MyMigrationConfiguration>());
        Context.Database.Initialize(true);


public abstract class MyMigrationConfiguration<TContext> : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TContext> 
    where TContext  : DbContext{

    protected  MyMigrationConfiguration() {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; 

    }
```

**EDIT: Added comment based on feedback**

Changing the Database to Match the schema means also the Migration history table will also need to be altered if it doesnt match.  Setting the Model Data binary by hand  to match your model, is not straight forward.
If your tables match your code, then the model recorded in __MigrationHistory as the last model, must be different. Your problem starts right there.
You can delete all entries from MigrationHistory table and try again. **[disclaimer.. take a copy of entries... etc**] But fighting EF isnt the ideal approach.
It also means you are in quasi DB first mode.  So i would suggest you **DON'T** continue on this path. Unless you plan on going to DB First mode.

What you are saying is you dont trust EF to do the right thing under code first scenarios.
Backup the DB.  Then try it.   If EF does the "WRONG" thing try and deal with that would be my suggestion.  If you have a nasty migration scenario EF cant handle, start a new question to get workarounds.

[image]
[image]

Comment: But I don't want to have the risk of EF doing the schema changes (the ones that I will be doing with "ALTERS", etc). Is this the only way?